# Can't change the desktop wallpaper or use nitrogen on Gnome Desktop

Tags: 16.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, desktop-background, gnome-tweak-tool

My original idea was to use different wallpapers for each monitor

in , I cannot choose a wallpaper at all.

[image: desktop]

When I press the windows button to pan between desktops, I can see the chosen wallpaper is there. But is overlayed with the same image.

[image: panning between desktops]

When I turn Tweak tool, Desktop->Icons on Desktop to ON, I can choose any image I want as a wallpaper. But now I can't use nitrogen to overlay multiple images (one for each screen).

How can I resolve this?

Comment: See https://www.blackmoreops.com/2015/07/10/use-different-wallpapers-on-multiple-monitors-in-linux/